# Joining strings characters one after one

Tags: python

How to join two or more strings in python with one character after another?

For example

```
a = 'hello'
b = 'world'

output = 'hweolellod'
```

Same goes for three or more strings. using `+` is not helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
''.join([x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)])
```

which gives:

```
'hweolrllod'
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `str.join` with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

a = 'hello'
b = 'world'

zipper = zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='')
res = ''.join(list(chain.from_iterable(zipper)))

print(res)

hweolrllod
```

**Explanation**

- `zip_longest` is used to account for inconsistent length strings.
- `zipper` here is a lazy iterator which iterates each character of `a` and `b` simultaneously by index.
- List creation, while not necessary, is more efficient with `str.join`.